# cts:near-query Marklogic on json documents

Tags: json, marklogic-9

I am using search:search like below

```
import module namespace search = "http://marklogic.com/appservices/search"  at "/MarkLogic/appservices/search/search.xqy";

let $options :=
 
 <options xmlns="http://marklogic.com/appservices/search">
  <concurrency-level>8</concurrency-level>
  <search-option>unfiltered</search-option>
  <transform-results apply="empty-snippet">
    <!-- @apply=snippet : to get snippet-->
    <per-match-tokens>30</per-match-tokens>
    <max-matches>4</max-matches>
    <max-snippet-chars>200</max-snippet-chars>
    <preferred-matches/>
  </transform-results>
  <term>
    <term-option>case-insensitive</term-option>
    <term-option>wildcarded</term-option>
    <term-option>stemmed</term-option>
    <term-option>diacritic-insensitive</term-option>
    <term-option>punctuation-insensitive</term-option>
  </term>
  
  <constraint name="title">
    <range collation="http://marklogic.com/collation/codepoint" type="xs:string" facet="false">
      <json-property>title</json-property>
    </range>
  </constraint>    
  <extract-document-data>
    <!-- Full Title -->
    <extract-path>/title</extract-path>    
  </extract-document-data>
  
  <additional-query>
    <cts:near-query distance="1" xmlns:cts="http://marklogic.com/cts">
      <cts:json-property-word-query>
        <cts:property>title</cts:property>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">chemotherapy</cts:text>
        <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
      </cts:json-property-word-query>
      <cts:json-property-word-query>
        <cts:property>title</cts:property>
        <cts:text xml:lang="en">hospital</cts:text>
        <cts:option>case-insensitive</cts:option>
      </cts:json-property-word-query>
      <cts:option>ordered</cts:option>
    </cts:near-query>
  </additional-query>
  <additional-query/>
</options>
return 
search:search('', $query, 1, 10)
```

Using this query I am getting the document with title, in the query distance between chemotherapy and hospital in 1

Result with title :{"title":"chemotherapy for cancer patients in the hospital."}

Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It worked after enabling the word position index in Db settings